# Access permissions for command file created with bash

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, permission

I wrote myself a simple bash script which is a wrapper for `compass create` function, plus it creates a command file in the directory for `compass watch` (so that instead of manually typing out the directory and watch every time, I just double click on an icon in the project folder). The problem is that I get the following error when opening the command file:

> The file “watch.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges. To view or change access privileges, select the file in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

I can run it from the terminal with `bash watch.command` (assuming I'm in the appropriate directory). I tried changing the permissions in finder for the file as well as the folder (read and write for everyone), but I still get the same error (plus I don't want to change permissions manually every time).

Also, if I open text mate and make exactly the same file and save it to my project directory, it runs as expected.

Here is the code for my `new_project` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
compass create "/Users/user_name/Desktop/$1" --bare --sass-dir "scss" --css-dir "css" --javascripts-dir "js" --images-dir "images";
echo "#!/bin/bash" >> "/Users/user_name/Desktop/$1/watch.command";
echo "cd /Users/user_name/Desktop/$1" >> "/Users/user_name/Desktop/$1/watch.command";
echo "compass watch" >> "/Users/user_name/Desktop/$1/watch.command";
```

(the `$1` argument is the project name)

Comment: what does `ls -l /Users/user_name/Desktop/$1/watch.command` show (replacing $1 by an actual directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod 700 watch.command` Now try double clicking the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make your script executable with

```
chmod +x $YourFile
```

See `man chmod` for more details, or https://ss64.com/osx/chmod.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod